# How to call functions with tkinter from existing script

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The title isnt very accurate i think

Here is the begining of my script

```
rom colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
import commands
import config
import sys

# Coloroma autoreset
init(autoreset=True)


while True:
    # Database Check.
    while True:
        db = input("Check for new databases? Y/N: ")
        if db.lower() == 'y':
            commands.db_download()
            break
        elif db.lower() == 'n':
            break
        else:
            continue
```

It's a bot to automatize some actions. Now i want to add some gui to it but i dont know how.

And here's the start of what i tried to do with tkinter

```
import tkinter
import questions


top = tkinter.Tk()

B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Lancer", command = db)

top.mainloop()
```

Like you see at the left, i have " import questions" but cuz of it when I launch the tkinter file, it automatically launches the questions without taking my "B" code into account.

How can I add gui to each command of my questions.py?

Comment: Please do not link to pictures if code. We test your code by running it, and to manually type in something you could have provided is considered testing our patience. Post code as text. Look up the formatting syntax.

Comment: @figbeam Voila! The change is done! Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import a script then it will run all the code in that script, if you want to only run certain parts of your script at a time you have to put those bits of code into functions.

For example:

```py
def coloroma_autoreset():
    init(autoreset=True)


    while True:
        # Database Check.
        while True:
            db = input("Check for new databases? Y/N: ")
            if db.lower() == 'y':
                commands.db_download()
                break
            elif db.lower() == 'n':
                break
            else:
                continue
```

> If this code was in a file "questions.py" you could then `import
>   questions` and run this function like this:

```py
import questions

questions.coloroma_autoreset() # this would run the code
```

> Another problem with your code is that you aren't displaying your
>   buttons, you need to use some sort of geometry manager that tkinter
>   offers to display any widgets you add to your window.

Like so:

```py
import tkinter
import questions


top = tkinter.Tk()

B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Lancer", command = db)
B.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh alright I get that point ! But how to add that to tkinter ? I tried but it didnt work :(

Comment: What didn't work, I have no idea what your problem is? What code are you trying to run when you press your button?

Comment: First of all, really thank you for your above answer, it helped me really much! 
What i mean is, i want at the launch of the gui for example a button with "Launch bot" (that i managed to do) and right after my script above starts. Like it asks "Check for new db?" and i have two buttons "Yes" or "No" and depending on what i click, it continues the corresponding code lines.That point i didnt manage to do. You understand what i mean? Sorry for my english :p